# ng-change function is not being called and no error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with a select box in angular and it appears like the ng-change function is never being called. This is the code for the select:

```
<select
    data-ng-options="choice.id as choice.singular for choice in model.doseUnitChoices"
    data-ng-model="ucumId"
    data-ng-change="updateForm()"
    class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I have simplified the code in the controler function to do the minimum needed:

```
  updateForm: function(){
    console.log('test');
  },
```

So far everything works like normal, the drop down shows all the available options, but when I select any option in the dropdown it immediately changes back to the last option, which may mean something, and the change function is never called and no errors appear in the console? Any ideas on how I can debug this issue and find out whats wrong?

UPDATE: interestingly I discovered while inspecting the element on the page is that actually all of the select elements are listed as selected, maybe there is an issue with the data being used as the model? Looking into it

Comment: just small Q, sure you are binding `updateForm` to `$scope` ?

Comment: Yes at the top of the controller file above the function we have "angular.extend($scope, {" and I am successfully hitting and using other functions within that scope from other onclick events, its just this select box that cant seem to call any on change functions..

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure because it is the first things that popped

Comment: @AndrewFont , can you create a plunker?

Comment: It's just a nitpick, but please add the missing `>` to the example code (it's missing from the `select` element).

Comment: Is this really in the code: <option value=""></option>?

Comment: Yea, its not the usual way I've seen it set up, but its the way the project has been set and so far for all other instances the code is working as expected.

Comment: Oh @MikeFeltman I was responding to Daniel Krom above, but yes the code really has <option value=""></option> and in all the other selects we have thats how its set up and they work as expected.

Comment: @JohnSmith the > is actually in the code if you look at the way its spaced out, remember the NG stuff is between the <select ... and ...  >

Comment: Nvm it was not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that the issue was being caused by two problems outside the scope of the question:

1. `ucumId` didn't exist when this select was being called, which I guess caused all the select options to be set as selected somehow?
2. because the above error was causing all the options to be 'selected', no matter what i did in the select it never updated the values so no change was occurring?

Anyway making sure 'ucumId' existed fixed the issue I was having,

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to duplicate it and with the minimum amount of code, it works fine.

```
<html>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
    <select 
        data-ng-options="choice as choice.label for choice in model.doseUnitChoices" 
        data-ng-model="ucumId" 
        data-ng-change="updateForm()"
        class="form-control input-sm">

        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js "></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("app",[]).controller("myController", myController)

        function myController($scope) {
            $scope.ucumId = "";

            $scope.updateForm = function(){
            console.log('test');
            };

            $scope.model = {}

            $scope.model.doseUnitChoices = [
                {id: 1, label: "one" },
                {id:2, label: "two" }
            ]

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect that either there's a small typo somewhere, updateForm is redefined somewhere or your controller is getting redefined somewhere. I'd suggest pairing down the actual code and removing things piece by piece until you get to a point where it's working or something like that.

Comment: Actually no 'Model' is a $scope variable we are using in the controller and update form is a $scope function